# Positioning absolute div inside relative container

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I have an image and want to show a rollover popup div on hover of that image. Below is my code;

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="popup">
        <li><a href="#"Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"Link 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="iOpenPopupOnHover.gif" /
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="popup">
        <li><a href="#"Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"Link 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="iOpenPopupOnHover.gif" /
</div>
...
```

Now I use position:relative for the wrapper and position: absolute for the popup. This is bcoz I want to position the popup at the top/center with respect to each image..

Now the issue is while the absolute position seems to be getting calculated with respect to the image, the popup is completely contained within the wrapper div and kind of crops some of the popup links. I want the complete popup to get displayed...How do I fix this?

Below is the CSS

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 105px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Hmm...yes...so silly of me..That solved the issue...But unfortunately I am facing another issue...I cannot use overflow:visible, as I use overflow:hidden for layout purpose (clearing floats, etc).. So I need some other way to position the popup based on mouse click location or so..

Comment: I want to show a rollover popup on click of some image..Though I am able to show the popup, it crops bcoz of the overflow:hidden..I use overflow:hidden for layout purpose and hence cannot change to overflow:visible (clearing floats, etc).. So I need some other way to position the popup based on mouse click location or so..

Comment: You could have the popup outside of the overflow: hidden container, positioned absolutely. Then when you click on an image, you set the left and top propeties of the popup using jQuery, based on the offset().top and offset().left properties of the image. If this doesn't make sense, chuck it in another question and we'll help you out :)